# Database design change with JPA

Tags: database, jpa

This is not really a issue but it is a sometimes annoying thing during my development. Let's say I have some entities (db is created according those entities, not otherwise) and I decided to add a column, drop a column or something and now I need to commit those changes to my DB.

What is the best way to do that? I sometimes have to restart Glassfish; sometimes deploying it is enough; sometimes I need to erase tables manually because restarting won't help. My strategy in `persistence.xml` is set to `Create` but other options didn't really help me.

Is there any standard approach for commiting changes from entities to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know there is no standard way in JPA to alter tables automagically during development and still keep the data in the table. For some cases switching to CREATE-DROP will do the trick - but then you will loose the data in the table and pretty quickly need to write scripts to populate said table. As you said it is not a big issue for you and it might be good practice to go from CREATE-DROP to a method that works in multi-person projects. My/our way is to have a sql script file in the repo, and when I alter my entites I (manually) alter that script or add a new script (the latter if the table is already in production or the data in the table is either more than a few line of inserts or created by use and not easily reproducable). This way we work with constantly merged and runnable code. Other project-members wanting to run the current development branch against a (local?) db where the table is out-of-date just needs to execute the sql script.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do too, I don't mind loosing data(respectively do mind but I know I can't avoid it). But point of my question was that sometimes takes a lot of time to commit changes to database and I don't know what to do to speed up the process(if I really need to restart server or deployement is enough, etc.)

Comment: Sounds like an IDE or building+deploying specific situation then. If you redeploy the application (ear-file) via asadmin the CREATE-DROP should definitly be executed correctly and not need restart of glassfish. If you deploy via maven-script or netbeans/eclipse/whatever there might be some configuration problem or even general cache/tmp-dir whatever problem.